# How to simulate a 'mousemove' Event and specify movementX and movementY in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine, mouseevent, mousemove

I am trying to write a Jasmine test for a 'mousemove' handler in TypeScript. Here you have my test:

```
    it('should pan', () =>
    {
        let mouseMoveEvent: MouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mousemove", { movementX: 1, movementY: 2 });
        canvas.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(mouseMoveEvent);
        fixture.detectChanges();

        expect(component.canvasManager.viewportOrigin.X).toBe(1, "expected pan on X");
        expect(component.canvasManager.viewportOrigin.Y).toBe(2, "expected pan on Y");

    });
```

The test is working/passing but there is a compilation error:

> ERROR in
>   src/app/components/biq-workflow-editor/tests/biq-workflow-editor.component.canvas-manager.spec.ts(63,76):
>   error TS2345: Argument of type '{ movementX: number; movementY:
>   number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MouseEventInit'.
>   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'movementX' does
>   not exist in type 'MouseEventInit'.

I understand that TypeScript compiler generates JavaScript code even when there is a compilation error.

How should I write the 'mousemove' event simulation in TypeScript so there won't be any compilation error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks valid to me. However, I was able to reproduce the same issue. I was able to work around it by by casting the second parameter as a `MouseEventInit` object.

`let mouseMoveEvent: MouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mousemove", <MouseEventInit>{ movementX: 1, movementY: 2 });`

Comment: That fixed my issue